# how to set fielddata=true in kibana

Tags: kibana

I am new to Kibana, have data loaded into Elastic 5.0.0-alpha3 and am using Kibana 5.0.0-alpha3 to Visualise. I can display some numeric fields as histograms but when I want to use text fields I get:

```
Visualize: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [publisher] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.
```

I am warned that the data (names of Publishers) may have been analyzed into subfields, but I'd like to display anyway.

How do I set `fielddata=true`?

EDIT: recent issues on Kibana github suggest that this is a new feature in 5.0.0 and is still awaiting an answer!

EDIT (following @Val's answer, and asking for Elastic newbie help, and hoping others will find it useful). The ingest script was:

```
fs = require('fs')

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
 host: 'localhost:9200',
 log: 'trace'
});

fs.readFile('/Users/pm286/workspace/cmdev/getpapers/20160602/crossref_results.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
   document = JSON.parse(data)
  document = JSON.parse(data)

  for(i=0;i<document.length;i++) {
      client.create({
          index: 'index',
          type: 'type',
          body: document[i]
          })
      }
  });
```

How do I include @Val's approach in this?

Comment: For aggregations on text fields, you don't need to set 'fieldData=true' anymore. Just use '<myFieldName>.keyword' field instead. Refer to Patrick B's answer for details.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In your ES mapping, you need to set [`fielddata:true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/fielddata.html) in your `publisher` field:

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
{
   "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "publisher": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
   }
}
```

You'll need to reindex your data after making this change, but afterwards Kibana won't complain anymore.

**UPDATE**

You can either execute the above query in the [Sense UI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/index.html) or through curl

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "publisher": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Or you can also execute it in your Javascript file just before creating your document:

```
client.indices.create({
  index: 'index',
  body: {
      "mappings": {
        "type": {
          "properties": {
            "publisher": {
              "type": "text",
              "fielddata": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have accepted/upvoted. As an Elastic newbie I'd appreciate knowing how/where to put this. See latest EDIT in question

Comment: Will test this and hopefully give the OK.

Comment: The second source code block contains a invalid JSON, it's not working example.

Comment: Thank you @TonyQ, it's been fixed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes preferably

Comment: Hi I have added "fielddata" : True but Still getting same error.

Comment: PUT /your_index/_mapping/your_type?update_all_types
worked for me. thanks.

Comment: why re-indexing is required after this change? what if i do not re-index after this change?

Comment: @BrijeshSoni not required anymore

Comment: You'll need to reindex your data after making this change, but afterwards Kibana won't complain anymore. ---- But it works without reindexing?

Answer (score 39):

Since you're using Elastic 5.x (5.2 is out now as I write this), you should instead use the new keyword support instead of enabling fielddata on an indexed field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/fielddata.html provides good information on the pros and cons and on how to set this.
From the page:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You then use the 'my_field' field for searches and the 'my_field.keyword' field for aggregations, sorting, or in scripts.

my_field.keyword is what you would use within Kibana / Grafana.

Comment: I know the OP was explicitly asking how to set fielddata = true, but this answer is what most users will want. Setting fielddata = true is highly discouraged by the Elastic team themselves, and using keyword yields the desired results without the negative performance impact. +1

Answer (score 27):

If you are coming from the book "ElasticsearchThe Definitive Guide", try changing this

```
"terms" : { "field" : "interests" },
```

to

```
"terms" : { "field" : "interests.keyword" },
```

So, the code to run will become;

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "all_interests": {
      "terms": { "field": "interests.keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We ran into this while building a proxy to search with Body Builder JS - when applying sorts to text fields with spaces, access it as a keyword was required.

Comment: Thank you! It is really works and without any extra changes with fielddata:true + reindex. Less headache with that way :)

Answer (score 8):

This code fixes this problem.

```
PUT megacorp/_mapping/employee
{
   "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "interests": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
   }
}
```

So this code will run thereafter:

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
    {
      "aggs": {
        "all_interests": {
          "terms": { "field": "interests"}
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

what is the field "your_type"?

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable fielddata on an existing text field, this is required to do aggregation on this field

```
PUT megacorp/_mapping/employee
{
  "properties": {
    "interests": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PUT your_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "your_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/text.html#enable-fielddata-text-fields)